# How to send MAC broadcast data frame with Android AP

Tags: android, android-ndk, wifi, android-wifi

I'm trying to use the Android wifi AP functionality to send a MAC broadcast frame that other devices listening within range will be able to pick up. Any ideas how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open a socket a send UDP packet to an IP broadcast address. It will automatically translated to a MAC broadcast address.